# Zerobrane: fractal-samples: zplane.lua is exiting with an error

Tags: zerobrane

I tried out some of the samples coming along with ZeroBraneStudio. 
`spirograph-samples` are working fine. May be there should be also a `wait()` statement at the end of the `livecoding-samples` and the `fractal-samples`. Otherwise the graphic window disappears at the end of execution. For
`fractal-samples: zplane.lua` I get an error:

```
Zoom: {1}
Cent: {0,0}
Area: {-2,2,-2,2}
/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/bin/lua.app
/Contents/MacOS/lua: ./fractal.lua:123: attempt to index local 'C' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
./fractal.lua:123: in function 'Draw'
..ts/ZeroBraneStudio/myprograms/fractal-samples/zplane.lua:103: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00001c80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version of fractal.lua there is no reference to `C` variable on line 123. I'd try a newer version, as I don't see any issue with the execution of zplane.lua with the [current version of fractal.lua](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneEduPack/blob/master/fractal.lua).

Comment: Thank you. I've downloaded the current  `ZeroBraneEduPack-master.zip` file.  The examples of the current version are working fine.